# Equivalence of two approximation algorithms for min Steiner tree

Tags: algorithms, graphs, proof-techniques

I learned two approximation algorithms for the **min Steiner tree**:

**The first algorithm:**

1- Compute the metric closure G' of G.

2- Compute a min spanning tree T' of G'

3- Construct the union U of the shortest paths in G which correspond to edges in T'

4- Output the Steiner tree T contained in U.

**The second algorithm:**

1-Find a cheapest path that connected two required vertices which are not yet connected.

2-Repeat until all required vertices are connected.

My question is: **can we write a proof to show that the equivalence of the two algorithms?**

I think that the 2 algorithms are equivalent since the second one is based on Prim's algorithm for min spanning tree; it directly connects required vertices without explicitly doing metric closure.. But can we write a mathematical proof to show the equivalence?

Note: I encountered this question in these slides (last slide)

https://www.slideserve.com/una/approximation-algorithms-combinatorial-approaches

Comment: I think you are referring to Distance Network Heuristic and Minimum Path Heuristic, both are proven to be 2*(1-1/p) approximations (where p is the number of mandatory nodes). But if you want to prove that they both produce the same Steiner Tree it's a different story and intuitively I think they can produce different trees